# ASP.NET MVC change content animation

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, animation, razor, frontend

I'm creating `Views` for an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm using `_Layout` and some other `Views` like Shop, Contact, etc., which have only one element: "content".

How can I set content change animation? I don't like white flashing while changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is unrelated to MVC and is the result of simple HTML page transitions. Since you're actually changing the entire page, the white flashing is the result of loading the new page.

You can manage this through CSS and jQuery. [Here is one article](https://onextrapixel.com/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/) that describes one way to manage page transitions. Just search for HTML Page Transitions and you'll see plenty of jQuery libraries made for this with extensive documentation.

[Here is one jQuery library I found: Animsition](http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/)

Some additional information on the white flickering you're seeing from [this article.](https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Web-page-performance-Removing-the-white-flicker-delay)

> Amongst the various problems with web page loading, white flicker is
>   considered to be one of the common issues which occurs during page
>   access, loading, reloading, and traversing Internet browsers. The
>   white flicker occurs for various reasons including the browser trying
>   to render the page before the style sheet has finished loading,
>   JavaScript issues and other rendering faults. Browsers will always
>   wait until everything (beyond images) has finished downloading before
>   rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of your css template, if It has spinners you should look in the documentation, if your template doesn´t have, look for one, there are a lot of template of spinners with documentation.
Here is an example of documentation (of course, this apply if you are using inspinia, but all of them have similar applications):
http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/spinners.html

Comment: Spinners only apply for ajax requests and only if they have that set up, or set up up to manage page transitions. Based on his question, I think they are simply using regular page transitions.

Comment: I know, I misunderstood what he was asking, but if he is using an extra container in his view, like an iframe, he can use spinners, thanks for your observation.